# How to deal with a client who doesn't pitch up to meetings on time?

Tags: difficult-client

One particular client is notorious for not keeping the skype meeting times we set up. On several occasions the meeting time has come and gone, and I've sent a message though and they have replied saying they're really busy and can we move the meeting to tomorrow.

These meeting times are usually agreed on a number of days in advance and are organised through Google calender. This isn't a matter of miscommunication.

How do I deal with this? It's getting to the point where it's becoming very inconvenient. I have mentioned to the client that I'd appreciate more warning, and I'm charging the client for the time I've spent waiting, but it seems like the respect and value for my time just isn't there. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Yikes, that sounds like a bad situation. If it's just not worth it to keep them, you may want to give [this question](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/q/935/9) a read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have dealt with this by setting a weekly meeting time once a week. If the client doesn't pitch up, they will be charged and will have to wait until the same time next week before I'm available to meet with them again. I won't organise a meeting outside of this time because inevitably they will forget and won't pitch up.

This has worked quite well, it has established a routine which means that the meeting is not forgotten as easily, and there is a premium on my time now, since the chance to meet with me is only once a week. The rest of my schedule is no longer inconvenienced by last minute meeting time changes.

Answer (score 4):

Either fire the client or charge for meeting time regardless of whether he's there or not. It was agreed upon... your time is billable, right?

If you are already billing for the time and the client is paying, even though they aren't showing up, I'm uncertain what the issue would be. I mean you're making money for nothing essentially. If the continued missing of scheduled meetings bothers you, even though you are being paid for the time, then the only real recourse is to quit working for the client.

Comment: I have been charging for the meeting time, however it doesn't seem to be a motivating factor, even though my rate is competitive.

Comment: Hey Scott and Stacey, can you please edit the info from the comments into your respective posts? We're not a discussion site, and information in comments can't be easily searched by people searching for answers to the same problem. Let's continue building a high-quality repository of knowledge, in Q&A format, that gives back and helps others.

Comment: @jmort253 done (and feel free to delete this comment :) )